# sscanf unexpected results inside a loop

Tags: c, string, fgets, scanf

I am trying to parse this simple configuration file using `fgets` and `sscanf`:

```
# configuration file for client
[user]
ID      34DV4gx7
NAME    Somebody
```

I wrote the following script to parse it, in which sscanf initially seems to be extracting the variables properly then for some unknown reason it mixes them up:

```
int main (void)
{
    FILE *conf;
    char *confname = "client.conf";
    char buf[256], tmp[256];
    char id[8];
    char name[12];
    char token[40];
    size_t i, count = 0, valid = 0, len = sizeof token;

    if ((conf = fopen (confname, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Failed to open configuration file %s\n", confname);
        return 1;
    }
    memset (id, 0, sizeof id);
    memset (name, 0, sizeof name);
    memset (token, 0, sizeof token);
    while (!feof (conf))
    {
        memset (buf, 0, sizeof buf);
        memset (tmp, 0, sizeof tmp);
        if (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, conf) == NULL) continue;
        if (buf[0] == '#' || buf[0] == '[') continue;
        if (sscanf (buf, "ID %s", tmp) == 1)
        {
            strncpy (id, tmp, sizeof id);
            id[strlen (id)] = '\0';
            printf ("id: %s[%d]\n", id, strlen (id));
            valid++;
            continue;
        }
        else if (sscanf (buf, "NAME %s", tmp) == 1)
        {
            strncpy (name, tmp, sizeof name);
            name[strlen (name)] = '\0';
            printf ("name: %s[%d]\n", name, strlen (name));
            valid++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    fclose (conf);

    printf ("id: %s\n", id);
    printf ("name: %s\n", name);

    if (valid != 2) return 2;
    for (i = 0; i < strlen (id) && count < len; i++) token[count++] = id[i];
    token[count++] = ':';
    for (i = 0; i < strlen (name) && count < len; i++) token[count++] = name[i];
    token[count] = '\0';
    printf ("token: %s\n", token);

    return 0;
}
```

**Result:**

```
id: 34DV4gx7[8]
name: Somebody[8]
id: 34DV4gx7Somebody
name: Somebody
token: 34DV4gx7Somebody:Somebody
```

**Expected:**

```
id: 34DV4gx7[8]
name: Somebody[8]
id: 34DV4gx7
name: Somebody
token: 34DV4gx7:Somebody
```

I tried many things to find out what's causing this behaviour but got nothing, I thought it could be that the id and name variables are not null terminated so I manually added \0 at the end and then I thought it could be that the buf is getting overwritten in the loop so I used memset to reset it and also reset all the char arrays and checked the length of everything but I just can't see what's going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Step 1: `while (!feof (conf))` --> `while (fgets (buf, sizeof buf, conf))`

Comment: Step 2 `id[strlen (id)] = '\0';` --> `id[sizeof id - 1] = '\0'`

Comment: Note that `name[strlen (name)] = '\0';` does not do anything useful. `strlen` reads `name` until it finds `'\0'` even if that is longer than the array. And then you set that `'\0'` you just found to `'\0'`.

Comment: @chux I am pretty sure your two comments are actually the answer to his problem. You should post them.

Comment: Thankx chux and Zan for the comments but the output is still the same

Comment: Sorry it's fixed now, not sure what was the problem though

Comment: I think the `id` variable was not getting terminated because its size is 8 which is the same as `34DV4gx7`, not sure though.

Comment: NEVER EVER USE `strncpy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, you're not properly adding the null byte to the end of `id` and `name` after calling `strncpy`.

From the man page:

> The strncpy() function is similar, except that not more than n bytes
>   of src  are copied. Thus, if there is no null byte among the first n
>   bytes of src, the result will not be null-terminated.

So after using `strncpy` you need to manually add a null byte as the last byte of the array.  What you're doing instead is using `strlen` to find the length of the string.  This function only works if the string is correctly null terminated, which after the `strncpy` call it might not be.

So instead of this:

```
id[strlen (id)] = '\0';
...
name[strlen (name)] = '\0';
```

Do this:

```
id[sizeof id - 1] = '\0';
...
name[sizeof name - 1] = '\0';
```

This adds the null byte as the last character.

Now to explain the behavior you were seeing:

When you first read in `id`, all 8 bytes of this array were populated with the 8 bytes of the string in question.  It printed correctly because `name` appears in memory immediately after `id` (I'll explain how I know this momentarily) and `name` was initialized to all zeros outside of the loop, so the first byte of `name` (which contains a null byte) effectively terminates `id`.

Then when you read in `name`, the null terminator for `id` (which was actually in `name`) was overwritten.  Then when you later print `id`, it prints the bytes from `id` but doesn't find the null byte, so it keeps reading the bytes where `name` lives until it finds the null terminator for that string and prints `34DV4gx7Somebody`.  The fact that `id` printed this was is how we know that `name` appears immediately after `id` in memory (in this particular case).

The reason you saw the error with `id` but not with `name` is because `id` wasn't big enough for the string you read in (so null terminator was not added), but `name` was big enough for its string (so a null terminator was added).

Comment: This explains everything. Thanx.